# Prevent API user from setting properties of a property

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, properties

I would like to prevent the user of one of my Objective-C objects from setting a property of a property of the object. Just like it is not possible to set the `origin` of a `frame` of `UIView`. I need this for the exact same reason: to be able to manage some side effects on the setter of the property.

Example:

```
@interface Time : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger hours;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger minutes;
@end

@interface Watch : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) Time *time;
@end
```

It now should not be possible to set the minutes directly by calling:

```
watch.time.minutes = 15;
```

…rather than:

```
Time *time = watch.time; // [watch.time copy]?
time.minutes = 15;
watch.time = time; // Here, in setTime:, I can implement some side effects
```

When trying to set a `UIView` `frame`'s size, the compiler complains like so: "Expression is not assignable". How could Apple’s framework developers have done this? Can this only be done with structs? How can I achieve a similar thing?

Comment: Yes, `frame` works this way only because [it's a struct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360068/mixing-c-structs-and-objective-c-properties), not because of any secret Apple magic.

Comment: I think this could be interesting for those who also are wondering: [Why is “expression not assignable” (UIView.frame.origin)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132757/why-is-expression-not-assignable-uiview-frame-origin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few options:

Prohibit the change entirely by returning a *copy* of `time` from its getter. You'll have to document the fact that this happens, and it may violate the principle of least surprise.

Use KVO to allow `Watch` instances to react to the fact that their `Time` member has been modified. As long as the modification goes through the `Time`'s setter (which it must for this situation), the `Watch` can do what it needs to do in `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`

Finally, consider whether `Time` even *needs* to be mutable. Probably your code here is just an example, but `Time` seems to be a value type. In general in Cocoa, these are not mutable. Changing the properties of `Time` that you don't want modified to `readonly` would solve this neatly for both you and the API user.

Comment: **Option 1**: I’d like to differ between calls from outside (where I’d return a copy) and calls from self (where I’d want the actual object). Do you see any possibility for doing so (using the getter, not the instance variable directly)? —

**Option 2**: Never done any KVO coding (except for getting/setting). Is there a possibility to observe changes of the whole object, not just single properties? …I guess you’d mentioned it, if there was one, but I’d like to be sure ;) —

**Option 3**: As stated in @mvadim answer, I’d prefer to keep the object mutable, but still this maybe the solution.

Comment: Also, thank you for your answer …the comment field was to small to be thankful in the first place ;)

Comment: For option 1, you could make the property private and just expose a public getter as a separate method. Cf. [`-[UIView constraints]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW171) For option 2, you don't need `Watch` to _observe_ changes to its own `time` property; just do whatever you need to do in `setTime:`

Comment: Of course, making the property private. I think I go for gate 1 or 3 :) …thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just add readonly to property:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger hours;
```

And then set you property to readwrite in *.m file:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger hours;
```

Add custom initialiser like:

```
-(id)initWithHours:(NSInteger)hours andMinutes:(NSInteger)min
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So far struggled with the idea to make the object immutable. But maybe I should reconsider…